# Can I do something like this in sinatra app? config files based on request

Tags: ruby, rest, sinatra

for the following code i'm getting config_file method is not available for the request. How can I do something like setting config file for entire app based on the request.

```
 namespace '/:id' do 
   before do
     if params[:id] == 'something'
       config_file 'configfile1.yml'
     else
       config_file 'configfile2.yml'
     end
   end 
 end
```

Comment: What's `config_file` here?

Comment: @Surya Please check this http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/config_file

Comment: @ank What kind of things do you want to change based on the :id? Can't you just put these things in regular yaml files?